# Azure Devop Pipelines: Is it possible to automatically modify the tags of the deployment group agent during (or as the last step to) a release?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-deploymentgroups

For example:

First, I register the device with a 'SETUP' tag.

Then I run a setup pipeline and at the end of that pipeline it removes the 'SETUP' tag and replaces it with a 'PRODUCTION' tag.

Is this possible?

Comment: Hi @PatrickK7, is the explanation in my answer helpful to you? If you have any questions about this, feel free to tell me.

Comment: Yes, makes sense. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, the **Tags** of deployment agent can be customized only on project-level. And the same deployment agent can be assigned different tags in different projects. Unlike the properties listed in **Capabilities**, the **Tags** is not a common property that can be shared cross-projects.

I checked and tried with the related API ([**Agents**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/agents?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1), [**Deploymentgroups**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/deploymentgroups?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1)) and Azure CLI ([**az pipelines agent**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/pipelines/agent?view=azure-cli-latest)), all of them are based on organization-level. I did not find any interfaces can be used to deal with the deployment agent on project-level.

So, in your case, currently we seem have no methods to automatically edit the tags of the deployment agent in the pipeline run. You may need to manually edit the tags.